# Smart / liquid inline spacing of divs

Tags: html, css

**I have a container, with two containers inside of it.**

```
<div id="container">

<div id="box1">
</div>

<div id="box2">
</div>

<div id="box3...4...">
</div>

</div>
```

I want the main container to span the entire width of the page. (Width: 100%;)

I want the two child containers to evenly spread and fill the horizontal space on the page.

I want to be able to add say a third or even forth child container and have them all fill from 50% 50% to ~33% ~33% ~33% to 25% 25% 25% 25% and so on...

If there a way to do this easily? Sorry if I didn't explain this well, it is my first time asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `flex` by specifying `display:flex` on the container and then `flex:1` (or `flex-grow:1` on the child elements like this :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container .box {
  flex: 1; /*or also `flex-grow:1` */

  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!-- container with 2 elements -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container with 3 elements -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container with 4 elements -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>

</div>
```

Refering to the documentation :

> The flex-grow CSS property specifies the flex grow factor of a flex
>   item. It specifies **what amount of space** inside the flex container the
>   item should take up. The flex grow factor of a flex item **is relative**
>   **to the size of the other children** in the flex-container.

You can read more about [flex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and [flex-grow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)